# Modify Visual Studio 2013 MVC Web Project Template CSS

Tags: css, templates, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013

Does anyone know what CSS class controls the width of the content area of the _Layout.cshtml and how to modify it (make it wider)?

I know it says

```
class="container body-content"
```

but I can't see how to modify it. I read it's better to modify the Site.css to override the bootstrap.css instead of modifying it directly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the default bootstrap.css is using the @media rule so it is doing different things at different resolutions which is why I was having a hard time tracking what was going on. So in my Site.css I override the behavior with my own settings like:

```
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
.container {
    max-width: 1840px;
    height: 800px;
}
```

and now it is the width I want.